# Sass not giving error for missing imported function

Tags: css, sass

**TLDR**:

Why does sass not give me an error saying I forgot to import a custom function?

---

I created a sass function:

```
$spacing: 5px;

@function spacing($multiplier) {
  @return $spacing * $multiplier;
}
```

I used it in many places, e.g

```
@import '../../styles/spacing.scss';


.item {
    margin-top: spacing(2);
}
```

In one file, I forgot to import the function file but I didn't get any error. Instead sass output `margin-top: spacing(2)`

[image]

And of course that's not a valid css rule.

How can I get a sass error to prevent this happening again?

Answer (score 1):

Per default, Sass treats it's a regular value, so it won't inform you about such errors. The best thing you can do is to add SCSS-lint to your project- there's a rule 'PropertySpelling` which would prevent from having invalid properties. See [description of this rule](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/rules/no-misspelled-properties.md). Or, if you may resolve to using Sass-lint (recommended solution), it has rule named [no-misspelled-properties](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/rules/no-misspelled-properties.md) which should do the trick for you